# How can I get the request URL used by Jquery ajax so I can test it directly in another tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on some ajax functions and it's inconvenient to have to reload the page and change the conditions every time. I want to directly trigger the command by simply loading the request into a tab. For example:

```js
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {beforeAjax(settings,1)},
                url: "backend.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: { 
                    mark_done: taskId,
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    if (ajaxErr(msg)) return;
                    
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ajaxFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)},
                done: function(xml) {alert(this.url)}
            });
```

What I want is to somehow get the full url request: http//site.com/?name=val&name=val string and print it to the console so I can easily copy and paste the result of the ajax call to test the backend function more efficiently. How can I do that?

Comment: You won't be able to _"load the request in a new tab"_ for POST requests

Comment: Good point. I'll change it to get - no reason not to is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull all the data for the request from the `settings` object. Add a listener for the `ajaxSend` event to capture all requests. To construct a full URL (in case of relative URLs), create a new [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) instance based from the current location

```js
$(document).on(
  "ajaxSend",
  (_event, _jqXhr, { url, type, contentType, data }) => {
    const fullUrl = new URL(url, window.location);
    console.log("[AJAX]", { fullUrl, type, contentType, data });
  }
);

// Relative URL with query params
$.get("some-relative-url", { with: "query-params" });

// Full URL
$.get("https://echo.zuplo.io/");

// Post request
$.post("https://echo.zuplo.io/", { some: "data" });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I attempted this but no success. When I log the settings value, I get nothing. ` function beforeAjax(settings,off=false)
 {
  // For testing
  console.log(settings);
  window.outgoingURL = settings.url + "?" + settings.data;
  console.log(outgoingURL);
  spinnerOn(off);   // Sets the spinner and tells it to force close once all ajax requests are done (just in case)
 }`

Comment: weirdly the settings value is present in the Beforesend function, but not when I send it to a secondary function. It disappears during the call somehow

Comment: To be clear, in this statement, the console.log works, but a matching one in the beforeAjax function does not: `beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {console.log(settings);beforeAjax(settings,1)},`

Comment: @not_a_generic_user I've updated my answer to use the `ajaxSend` event instead so as not to interfere with your existing code and included some examples

Comment: That gets the job done. Thank you!